# ¿Qué archivo regenera index.php en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Quiero borrar archivo index.php en Wordpress, pero siempre que lo borro vuele a aparecer.

¿Cómo puedo evitar esto?

Gracias.

Comment: No se exactamente lo que intentas hacer. El archivo `index.php` de la carpeta raíz es el archivo por defecto en Wordpress. Si no existe, se creará automáticamente. Si lo que deseas es cambiar el comportamiento de Wordpress, debes revisar la configuración de tu implementación, no uso Wordpress y no te puedo asegurar que exista una forma de cambiar el comportamiento. Por otro lado, puedes usar un archivo `.htaccess` para indicarle al servidor el orden de lectura de los archivos en el directorio. En fin, creo que tienes algunas alternativas. Todo dependerá de lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Si piensas usar Wordpress no puedes borrar el archivo `index.php`, porque es el archivo que Wordpress usa para cargar el contenido fundamental del sitio.

Si revisas [el código fuente de Wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/index.php), este es el contenido de `index.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Los comentarios lo dicen todo, esto es lo que hace `index.php` sin lo cual WP no funcionaría:

```
  * Frente a la aplicación de WordPress. Este archivo no hace nada, pero carga
  * wp-blog-header.php que hace y le dice a WordPress que cargue el tema.

    ...

  * Le dice a WordPress que cargue el tema de WordPress y lo genere

    ...

  * Carga el ambiente y la plantilla de WordPress
```

En [Wordpress Files](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Files) puedes ver también que aparece el sentido de `index.php`:

> **`index.php`**
>
> Core WordPress index. This is the file that produces the blog output.
>
> ---
>
> **`index.php`**
>
> Índice de WordPress Core. Este es el archivo que produce la salida del blog.

En conclusión, si piensas usar Wordpress, no tienes por qué borrar el archivo `index.php`